# Remove error code for xml attribute -- MS SQL For xml (_x003D)

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-attribute, for-xml

I have the following sql code to generate a block of xml.

```
SELECT top 1
'http://www.crsoftwareinc.com/xml/ns/titanium/common/v1_0' AS [xmlns],
(SELECT top 1
count(*)AS 'number-of-accounts',
--
-- TO DO
--
FOR XML PATH('payment-import-header'), TYPE),
FOR XML RAW ('consumer-payment-import-job');
```

The putout is this: 
[image]

How can I get rid of "_x003D" from the attribute name? If I insert "=" or "@" it will add another random value. I'm assuming these are error tags.

Thanks

Comment: Try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/add-namespaces-to-queries-with-with-xmlnamespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a default namespace using the [`WITH XMLNAMESPACES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/with-xmlnamespaces) clause, with the `DEFAULT` keyword.

Example:

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.crsoftwareinc.com/xml/ns/titanium/common/v1_0')
SELECT 1
FOR XML PATH('consumer-payment-import-job');
```

With result

```
<consumer-payment-import-job xmlns="http://www.crsoftwareinc.com/xml/ns/titanium/common/v1_0">1</consumer-payment-import-job>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this will create an attribute for all elements, I only want it for consumer-payment-import-job.

Comment: @aridi Sadly, there is no straightforward way to do this if you have multiple `FOR XML` clauses in your query. There is a [microsoft connect issue with a request to suppress adding the namespace to each element for multiple `FOR XML` clauses](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/265956/suppress-namespace-attributes-in-nested-select-for-xml-statements). If you could upvote it, maybe they'll make this possible in the future.

Comment: @aridi The workaround involves string functions btw, I'm sure you can figure this out yourself.